# Derive the mean and variance function and determine whether or not the following process is stationary

Tags: time-series, variance, autocorrelation, stationarity, autoregressive

Question:

Derive the mean and variance function and determine whether or not the following process is stationary.

$W_t = Y_t − Y_{t−1}$, for $Y_t = 2 + te_t$, where $e_t$ is the white noise series with normal distribution $N(0, σ^2_e)$

My work so far:

$Var(W_t) = Var(Y_t-Y_{t-1})= Var(Y_t)+Var(Y_{t-1})= Var(2 + te_{t})+Var(2 - (t-1)e_{t-1})$, since

And so,

$Var(W_t)=t^2 σ^2_e+ (t-1)^2 σ^2_e =(2t^2-2t+1)σ^2_e$

Since $Var(W_t)$ varies with $t$,  $\{W_t \}$ is not stationary.

Am I correct here? I appreciate your suggestions. Thank you so much for your time.